# Split cell between specified characters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a cell containing:  GB10_4.12.2014

I need to split into a new cell the number(s) to the right of the second character and to the left of the "_", which in this case is 10.

Another cell contains:  MC1_4.12.2014

In this case the function would return the number 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your value is in A1 cell try this way:

```
 =MID(A1,3,FIND("_",A1)-3)
```